# Rails todo list hide create column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I add the title and description with the todo_list form, then add the content to the todo_item form. But I want to register the todo_list title field in the title field on each line I create todo_item. How can I provide this on the controller side?

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo_list
  before_action :set_todo_item, except: [:create]

  def create
      @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.create(todo_item_params)

      redirect_to @todo_list
  end  

end
```

todo_item model

```
class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :todo_list

 def completed?
  !completed_at.blank?
 end
end
```

todo_list model

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :todo_items
end
```

todo_item db

```
class CreateTodoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :todo_items do |t|
     t.string :title
     t.string :content
     t.references :todo_list, index: true

     t.timestamps
   end
  end
end
```

todo list db

```
class CreateTodoLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :todo_lists do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

todo list _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
   <% if @todo_list.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
       <h2><%= pluralize(@todo_list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited 
 this todo_list from being saved:</h2>

       <ul>
       <% @todo_list.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
         <li><%= message %></li>
       <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
   <% end %>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :title %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :title %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :description %><br>
     <%= f.text_area :description %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
```

todo item _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@todo_list, @todo_list.todo_items.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "New Todo" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

todo item _todo_item_html.erb

```
<div class="row clearfix">
     <% if todo_item.completed? %>
         <div class="complete">
             <%= link_to complete_todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, 
 todo_item.id), method: :patch do %>
                 <i style="opacity: 0.4;" class="fa fa-check"></i>
             <% end %>
         </div>
         div class="todo_item">
             <p style="opacity: 0.4;"><strike><%= todo_item.content %>
 </strike></p>
         </div>
         <div class="trash">
             <%= link_to todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), 
 method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
             <% end %>
         </div>
     <% else %>
         <div class="complete">
             <%= link_to complete_todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, 
 todo_item.id), method: :patch do %>
                 <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
             <% end %>
         </div>
         <div class="todo_item">
             <p><%= todo_item.content %></p>
         </div>
         <div class="trash">
             <%= link_to todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), 
 method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
                 <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
             <% end %>
         </div>
     <% end %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are trying to do I guess,
Add this in your `ToDoItem` model..

```
before_create :set_title

def set_title
  self.title = todo_list.title
end
```

Hope it helps..

---

Update, as requested in comments.

Updating children when parent is updated.

In your `TodoList` model,

```
before_save :update_todo_item_titles

def update_todo_item_titles
  todo_items.update_all(title: title) if title_changed?
end
```

Comment: Hello
Ferhan todo list title When I edit my title, how do I change the title of the todo item?

Comment: Change `before_create` to `before_save`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Todo_list title is edited, but todo_item title is not updated.

Comment: ohh, you want to update children when parent is updated, then see my updated answer, if it still doesn't help, please raise another different question here.